# How to find a node without parent with jscodeshift?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, jscodeshift

I want to find call expressions that doesn't have any parent in this script:

```
1 + 1

function parent() {
    2 + 2
}

3 + 3
```

Here I want to get `1 + 1` and `3 + 3` nodes but not `2 + 2`.

What I'd like to achieve would be something like:

```
j(file.source).find(j.ExpressionStatement, {
    parent: null 
});
```

So *is there a filter that allow to find if an expression has a parent ?*

[Here is a real use case.](https://github.com/BuonOmo/CommonJS-to-ES6-codemod/blob/ae1b42a26182752d7b261a28de6fbeb4da8c324e/transforms/variable-require-to-import-default.js#L1-L11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Using Indentation (unsafe)

The loc attribute of an AST node has an indentation attribute. If the indentation is `0` when can assume that is a top level expression:

```
j(file.source).find(j.ExpressionStatement, {
    loc: {indent: 0} 
});
```

This is really not robust since it depends on indentation.

## Chaining with a second filter

Since I couldn't find a safe way to filter over the attributes. We can also use jscodeshift's `.filter()` to get the parent node. If it is the program, then we're sure to be top-level:

```
j(file.source).find(j.ExpressionStatement)
              .filter(path => j.Program.check(path.parent.value));
```